# Design issues in new iPhone X

Tags: ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I tested my Apps on `iPhone X` Simulator, due to new screen addition in the iOS Family, on various screen I faced stretched background images and its showing vertical spacing issues as well, I want my Previous Apps to work perfectly on the `iPhone X`.
What should be the Aspect ratio that works perfectly on all the iPhone Devices including `iPhone X`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Comment: There is no single aspect ration that "works on all the iPhone Devices including iPhone X". The 5, 6, 7 and 8 series all have (almost) the same ratio. The iPhone X is thinner/taller.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has newly introduced `Safe area` to bound your app design within that area.

There is no specific `ratio` for all devices, `Safe area` differs based on Devices and Mode they are in `Portrait/Landscape`. If you app supports `Auto Layout`, You can manage it quickly by changing constraints.

Please refer apple guidelines for more information regarding design you should follow - [iPhone-X Interface Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/)